# New Form Field Not Displaying on Publishing Page - SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, layout, publishing

I'm updating a publishing page in SP 2007 to include two hyperlink fields.

I've added the site columns and site content types, and updated the page layout with:

```html
<SharePointWebControls:CurrencyField FieldName="ExistingField1" runat="server" />
<br />
<SharePointWebControls:UrlField FieldName="NewField1" runat="server" />
<br />
<SharePointWebControls:CurrencyField FieldName="ExistingField2" runat="server" />
<br />
<SharePointWebControls:UrlField FieldName="NewField2" runat="server" />
```

When I open the page in edit mode, neither of the two newly added fields are there. The page source simply displays the old fields with an addition 
 where the new field should be.

```html
<div align="left" class="ms-formfieldcontainer"><div class="ms-formfieldlabelcontainer" nowrap="nowrap"><span class="ms-formfieldlabel" nowrap="nowrap">Existing Field 1</span></div><div class="ms-formfieldvaluecontainer"><span dir="none">
<input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$EditModePanelB$ctl49$ctl00$TextField" type="text" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_EditModePanelB_ctl49_ctl00_TextField" title="Existing Field 1" class="ms-input" Size="11" style="ime-mode:inactive;" /><br>
</span></div></div>
<br />
<br />
<div align="left" class="ms-formfieldcontainer"><div class="ms-formfieldlabelcontainer" nowrap="nowrap"><span class="ms-formfieldlabel" nowrap="nowrap">Existing Field 2</span></div><div class="ms-formfieldvaluecontainer"><span dir="none">
<input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$EditModePanelB$ctl51$ctl00$TextField" type="text" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_EditModePanelB_ctl51_ctl00_TextField" title="Existing Field 2" class="ms-input" Size="11" style="ime-mode:inactive;" /><br>
</span></div></div>
<br />
```

I have checked a dozen times to make sure my Field Names are typed correctly and checked the layout in, then out, and approved the layout multiple time.

Any ideas?

Comment: I figured out what was going wrong. The new columns also have to be added to the page list in addition to the site column and content types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going wrong. The new columns also have to be added to the page list in addition to the site column and content types. I should have seen that one coming from a mile away. (Forehead meets desk) =P